# Operator overload between pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

How can I overload operator + between two pointers pointing to a new class  object ?
e.g

```
class A{

}

A* operator+(A* p1,A*p2){
   return A;
}
```

I'm using objects only with pointers so I need to use pointers.

Comment: Pointers can already be added... can't they?

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/ Are you aware you can dereference pointers?

Comment: Just in the overload function.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: You can add a pointer and a number, or subtract two pointers.

Answer (score 1):

> How can i overload operator + between two pointers?

The standard doesn't allow for both parameters to the `operator+` to be pointers:

> `§[expr.add]/1` For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic or
>   unscoped enumeration type, or **one operand shall be a pointer** to a
>   completely-defined object type and **the other shall have integral or
>   unscoped enumeration type.**